# Where should I put a .vim plugin?

Tags: vi

this is the file:
https://github.com/mozilla/rust/blob/master/src/etc/vim/syntax/rust.vim

this is for rust [a new language from Mozilla] syntax highlight(?) in VIM
They provided 3 .vim files actually.
where should I put them?

Comment: What sort of linux/vim distribution ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That looks like a syntax highlight file, so put it in

```
~/.vim/syntax/rust.vim
```

Create the directories as necessary. See the Vim documentation on [`:syn-files`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-files) for more information.

Comment: type :help mysyntaxfile to get more details to copy any syntax files manually.  Any manually copied files need to be in this directory, so that if you upgrade to next version of Vim, you don't have to redo all this setup again.

Answer (score 2):

GNU Linux (see Greg's answer):
`~/.vim/syntax/rust.vim`

Windows:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\syntax`